# Spring Rest PostMapping from a json map into multiple tables

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, hashmap, spring-rest

I want to save json which is in map format into the database.

I am able to `@Getmapping` of the data in the different unrelated tables into json object but i am unable to save the same json format into the two tables in one method. here is my code and json:

```
@RestController
public class NewServiceController {

    @Autowired
    EsbcoreServiceRepository serviceRepo;

    @Autowired
    EsbcoreRuleRepository ruleRepo;

    @Autowired
    EsbcoreServiceDestinationRepository serviceDestinationRepo;

    @GetMapping(value="/api/allservices")
    public Map<String, Object> getAllServices() {       
        Map<String, Object> servicesMap=new HashMap<String, Object>();
        servicesMap.put("services", serviceRepo.findAll());
        servicesMap.put("rules", ruleRepo.findAll());       
        return servicesMap;         
    }

    @PostMapping(value="/api/allservices")
    public Object addnewservice(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> datamap) {
        //Map<String, Object> servicesMap=new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Object esbcoreRule=datamap.get("rules");
        Object esbcoreService=datamap.get("services");
        ruleRepo.save(esbcoreRule);
        //serviceRepo.save(esbcoreService);     
        return datamap;         
    }
}
```

JSON USED:

```
{
    "rules":
     [
        {
           "ruleId": 906,
            "ruleOrder": 9,
            "serviceId":
             {
                "serviceId": 908
             }

         } ],
    "services": 
    [

       {
            "serviceId": 908,
            "serviceCode": "0221",
            "systemDomainId": 37,
            "serviceType": "SOAP",
            "serviceName": "Customer",
            "operation": "MandateReActivate",
            "version": "1.0",
            "sync": 1,
            "logLevel": "DEBUG",
            "duplicateCheck": 1,
            "genericReply": 0,
            "timeout": 30,
            "retryMax": 0,
            "retryInterval": 0,
            "prjReleaseCode": "FINTECH_3.0.0",
            "emailAlertGroup": null,
            "smsAlertGroup": null,
            "emailAlertFlag": 1,
            "smsAlertFlag": 1,
            "creationDate": "2018-11-08T04:37:20.000+0000",
            "createdBy": "GGMAINA"
        }
    ]
}
```

The line `ruleRepo.save(esbcoreRule);` normally saves when the return type is of the modelname/database object name, but in this case that same line has this error:

> The method save(s) in the type crudrepository
>   is not applicable for the arguments (object)

Answer (score 0):

I changed my approach, the problem was in casting from type Object to EsbcoreRule,EsbCoreService,etc. I used gson instead, here is my code:

```
 @PostMapping(value="/api/allservices")
public Object addnewservice(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> datamap)
{
     //Gson gson= new Gson();
     Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

     Object esbcoreService=datamap.get("services");
     //Object esbcoreServiceT=datamap.get("servicesT");
     Object esbcoreRule=datamap.get("rules");
     Object esbcoreRuleCondition =datamap.get("ruleConditions");
     Object esbcoreRuleDestination=datamap.get("ruleDestinations");
     Object esbcoreServiceDestination=datamap.get("serviceDestinations");



    EsbcoreRule rule= gson.fromJson(esbcoreRule.toString(),EsbcoreRule.class);
    EsbcoreService service=gson.fromJson(esbcoreService.toString(),EsbcoreService.class);
    //EsbcoreService serviceT=gson.fromJson(esbcoreServiceT.toString(),EsbcoreService.class);
    EsbcoreRuleCondition ruleCondition=gson.fromJson(esbcoreRuleCondition.toString(),EsbcoreRuleCondition.class);
    EsbcoreRuleDestination ruleDestination=gson.fromJson(esbcoreRuleDestination.toString(),EsbcoreRuleDestination.class);
    EsbcoreServiceDestination serviceDestination=gson.fromJson(esbcoreServiceDestination.toString(),EsbcoreServiceDestination.class);


    serviceRepo.save(service);
    //serviceRepo.save(serviceT);
    ruleRepo.save(rule);
    ruleConditionRepo.save(ruleCondition);
    ruleDestinationRepo.save(ruleDestination);
    serviceDestinationRepo.save(serviceDestination);





    return datamap;

}
```